# Canon EOS 650D + Canon 50mm f/1.8 lens calibration

Tags: lens, canon, 50mm, canon-650d, front-focus

I have the Canon EOS 650D with Canon 50mm f/1.8 II lens.

After some tests I mentioned that I have ~1cm front focusing (see [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/37884/missing-focus-with-canon-50mm-1-8-lens-is-it-the-lens-or-me)).

Is there any way to calibrate Camera/Lens without disassembling them?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't panic just yet. As noted in a comment to the other question, I don't think your results are quite final yet.

Assuming there is an issue, there's one way: sent them together into Canon for service. They may do this for free  (Pentax did with my K10D, before Pentax started including a micro-adjust feature on their cameras), but may charge some (I wouldn't be surprised if they rule this as within acceptable tolerances for a $100 lens). They'll do the work on an optical bench and get it just right; if you send in multiple lenses, they can test the whole set and select the appropriate compromise (the camera probably doesn't have a way to remember different settings for different lenses, as a higher-end model would).

Other alternatives are:

- use live view and contrast-detect focus when critical focus is crucial.
- or, manually focus.
- learn to live with it; it's only a little bit of focus error and if you stop down a bit it won't matter.
- and, make sure to buy a camera with focus adjust as a user-accessible feature next time.

Comment: Which entry-level cameras have focus adjustment?

Comment: I'm pretty sure _none_; this is one of several reasons I recommend people who are serious about photography skip the "entry level" and [enter a little higher up](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5883/are-there-disadvantages-to-a-prosumer-camera-for-a-beginner-aside-from-cost) instead.

Comment: Wait, actually, the [Pentax K-30](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/pentax-k-30) _does_. In general, the smaller brands are more likely to have advanced features on their entry-level cameras, because the bigger brands have to worry more about competing with their _own_ higher end.